# Evaluating $\iint_S \sqrt{1+4x^2}\, dS$

Tags: definite-integrals

I have to compute $\iint_S \sqrt{1+4x^2} dS$ and I'm looking a way to do it. The graph seems to be:

the surface $S$ is given by ($x=0, x=2, y=0, y=3$ and $z=x^2$)

[image]

Can anyone help me set up the integral to compute it?

Comment: You have to parametrize $S$, what have u tried?

Comment: @Marcos I'm not sure on the parametrization. Not seems to be easy for this surface

Comment: notice that the only reltion you have is $z=x^2$, so the only reasonable parametrization is $f(x,y)=(x,y,x^2)$. Can you continue from this?

Comment: Initially I have $x,y,z$ so th parametrization reduce to $x,y$ but how about the limits? should be $\int_{0}^2\int_{0}^{x^2} \sqrt{1+4x^2}dy\ dz$ I cannot see it.

Comment: check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral, there is a formula for the integral given a parametrization

Comment: Notice also that this is a closed surface. If you're evaluating the surface integral, ensure you account for all faces/sides of the solid.

Comment: `Integrate[
 Sqrt[1 + (2 x)^2]/({-2 x, 0, 1} . {0, 0, 1}/Norm[{2 x, 0, -1}]), {x, 
  0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]` should give you 76/3

Comment: @Valent your surface is not defined the way it is written. You need another bound of $z$ or if it is just the surface of the parabolic cylinder for given bounds of $x$ and $y$, then it must be stated that way.

Comment: I believe that we need variation in $x,y,z$ right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, before I calculate surface area, I compute $\iint_S  dS = \text{surface area}$.
The area is easy to compute since you can compute the arc length and one side is constant i.e.
$$
\int_0^2 \sqrt{ 1 + (\frac{dz}{dx} )^2} dx = \text{arc length} \implies \int_0^3  \int_0^2 \sqrt{ 1 + (\frac{dz}{dx} )^2} dx  dy = \text{surface area}
$$
This gives
$$
\iint_S \sqrt{1 + (2x)^2} dS = \int_0^3  \int_0^2 \ (1 + (2x)^2) dx dy
$$
Another way, note that $d\vec S \cdot \hat k = dydx \implies dS \hat n \cdot \hat k = dydx$. This gives
$$
dS = \frac{dydx}{\hat n \cdot k}
$$
where $\hat n$ is a **unit** normal vector of the surface which you can obtain by taking the gradient of $z - x^2$.

Another way, you can parameterize the surface in terms of $s$ and $t$. You may write it as $\vec r (s, t) = s \hat i + t \hat j + s^2 \hat k$ with $0 \le s, t \le 2$. Now, in your function replace $x \to s, y\to t, z \to s^2$ and you may use the formula
$$
\iint_{T} f(\vec r(s, t)) \left \|\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial t}\right \| \mathrm{d} s \mathrm{~d} t
$$
All should give the same answer.

Comment: The question does not say that we need to find  integral only over the surface $z = x^2$. What part in the question tells you that you are not supposed to integrate over planar surfaces $x = 0, x = 2, y = 0$ and $y = 3$?